# Angular 1.5 component tree deep transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude, angularjs-components

I'm trying to figure out a way to use transclusion to provide a template for a deeply-nested component, from the top-level ancestor component. The idea being this component tree can be reused, but the markup for the lowest level component can be customized per use. I can't seem to find a way to pass the content through multiple components.

```
<parent-component>
  <h2>{{ grandchild.title }}</h2>
</parent-component>

angular.module('parent', ['child']).component('parentComponent', {
  template: '<child-component></child-component>',
  transclude: true
});

angular.module('child', ['grandchild']).component('childComponent', {
  template: '<grand-child-component></grand-child-component>'
});

angular.module('grandchild', []).component('grandChildComponent', {
  template: '<div>How to get transcluded content with correct context here?!?</div>'
});
```